# Need advice tracing and troubleshooting old to new wiring and an accidental ring circuit in 100 year old US house

Tags: electrical, wiring, mwbc, knob-and-tube, old-work

I'm in the US (Minnesota) in 100 year old house that has a c.1980 Square D 150 amp panel. I am working to de-energize some knob-and-tube I've recently discovered that is buried under insulation in the attic. Since I discovered this knob and tube I've had to reassess what I thought I knew about the wiring in this house. I have confirmed that all of the wiring at the panel is updated. I have confirmed that most of the wiring in the house is updated. I can see where the new wire for the circuit enters the attic. As I continue on this task I keep discovering new issues.

1. As part of exploring if I needed to rewire back to the panel, I discovered that this circuit is a part of a Multi-Wire-Branch-Circuit that is not handle-tied together or even adjacent in the panel (21 and 29) AND (of course) they are on the same phase. (I confirmed this with a Multimeter). I think the only good news is that these are mostly powering LED lights and phone chargers. And most of the circuit has been updated. And at least this means this wire is shaped differently than most of the other 14 gauge romex since it is round with an extra wire in it.
2. Of course there is one other circuit in the panel that uses this same 14 gauge round wire and it goes to all our smoke alarms, and somehow this wiring is also connected to the above circuit. The smoke alarms on circuit 11 can only be de-energized by turning off both 11 and 21 . Oddly, everything works just fine. I have searched but not been able to identify where these are tied together. The Smoke alarms oddly seem to be only on circuit 11 on the first floor and in the basement, but on the 2nd floor they are somehow also connected to 21.
3. Also, I don't really understand why the smoke alarms are still powered by 21 but the lights for 21 are not powered by 11 when 21 is off.

4)I'm not an electrician, but I'm patient, persistent and willing to turn off the power and to do research.

5. So I have 2 issues at the moment. I've found one spot where new and old wires are connected, but its connected not to the knob and tube but to snakeskin wiring that runs to a very rarely used receptacle.  So I still haven't found where the knob and tube connects to either the romex or the snakeskin. Do I just keep swimming thru the insulation from box to box? Is there an easier way?
6. I would also appreciate advice and strategies on how to determine where the two circuits are connected and if needing to turn off power to both to de-energize means it is an accidental ring circuit.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: My house is similar although slightly less chaotic. The splices into K&T are all in the basement except one which is in a weird spot in the wall from a bathroom reno. Absolutely none in the attic, although also no junction boxes there -- K&T doesn't use junction boxes.